# How to use innerHTML with JavaScript if/else statement and Bootstrap 4 dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

My application is pretty much done, I'm just having trouble incorporating the innerHTML statements when a user does not select an item from my two drop down menus. I currently know how to do this with alerts, but I want the message to appear on the page itself when the user does not make selections. I'm a beginner to JS- I understand this would be incorporating innerHTML with if/else statements however I'm having some trouble finding the correct way to accomplish this.

Goal: If user does not select eye color from dropdown menu on click of SUBMIT button innerHTML message should say "Please select an eye color."

Else if,
If user does not select skin tone from dropdown menu on click of SUBMIT button innerHTML message should say "Please select a skin tone."

Else, if user does not select eye color && skintone from dropdown menu on click of SUBMIT button innerHTMl message should say "Please select an eye color & skin tone."

Here is my HTML and JS [image]code:

```
        <h3 class="display-4" style="font-size: 1.5rem;">What is your eye color</h3>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="input-group justify-content-center">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-md dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="background-color: #588c7e;">
                    Eye Color

                </button>

                <div class="dropdown-menu" onchange="selectMenu1" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" id="eyeColor">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="brown" ><img src="img/brown_eye.jpg" class="rounded-circle"> Brown</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="blue" ><img src="img/blue_eye.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Blue</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="green" ><img src="img/green_eye.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Green</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="hazel" ><img src="img/hazel_eye.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Hazel</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Drop down Item 2-->

    <h3 class="display-4" style="font-size: 1.5rem;"> What is your skin tone</h3>
    <div id="menu2" class="dropdown">
        <div class="input-group justify-content-center">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-md dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="background-color: #588c7e;">
                    Skin Tone
                </button>

                <div class="dropdown-menu" onchange="selectMenu2"  aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="fair"><img src="img/fair.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Fair</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="light"><img src="img/light.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Light</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="medium"><img src="img/medium.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Medium</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="bronze"><img src="img/bronze_dark.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Bronze</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="tan"><img src="img/tan.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Tan</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="rich"><img src="img/dark.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Rich</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <!--Result Button-->

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg active" title ="Submit" style="background-color: #3e4444;" onclick="validate()" id="demo"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right fa-lg"></i></button>

<script>
function validate() {
    var eyeColor;
    var skinTone;

    if(!eyeColor){
        document.getElementById("eyeColor").innerHTML = "Please select an eye color";
    } else if (!skinTone){
        document.getElementById("skinTone").innerHTML = "Please select a skin tone";
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: What if the user doesn't select an eye color or skin tone?

Comment: if u can find it in your heart to use native HTML select with HTML5 form validation, all the work will be done for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging, I found a way where I didn't have to change any of my code. In fact I just had to add bit more code. I actually wasn't too far off from my original code:

HTML :

```
<div class ="dropdown-menu" id="eyeColor">
```

I added this  to each of my drop downs

```
<div class="error" id="error"></div>
```

Then my JS-

I got rid of this:

```
function validate() {
    var eyeColor;
    var skinTone;
```

and added this:

```
if (!eyeColor){
  document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "<span class='error'>Please choose an eye color</span>";
}
else if (!skinTone){
  document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "<span class='error'>Please choose a skin tone</span>";
}
```

}

I decided to style it a bit. I added a span with a class of 'error' and did this in my CSS:

```
.error {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Works like a charm! Just like I was hoping!

Comment: Huh, you added two label elements with the same `id` to the two drop downs? Won't that place the same error message in both drop downs simultaneously? If your `var eyeColor` and `var skinTone` don't exist, then won't the error message always appear?

Answer (score 1):

In your `validate()` method you are creating two variables called `eyeColor` and `skinTone` without ever setting their values, also your two if statements validate if the variables have a value which they do not, thus the innerHTML will never be hit.

You also need to create an element where the message should be placed as you are currently going to overwrite all of the child elements.

For example, create a label element before the submit button.

```
<label id="error"></label>
```

You should create two global variables and set them as an empty string.

```
var eyeColor = '';
var skinTone = '';
```

You're missing an id for the second dropdown menu. Add `id="skinTone"` to the `div` element.

Remove your two `onchange` functions as they won't work with `<div>` elements: `selectMenu1()` and `selectMenu2()`. Do however create an additional function which sets the value for the `eyeColor` and `skinTone` variables. For each `<a>` element within you dropdown menus, set the `href` to `href="javascript:setMenuValue(this)"`.

```
function setMenuValue(obj)
{
    if (obj !== undefined)
    {
        if (obj.parentElement.id == 'eyeColor')
        {
            // Update the global variable eyeColor
            eyeColor = obj.getAttribute('data');
        }
        else if (obj.parentElement.id == 'skinTone')
        {
            // Update the global variable skinTone
            skinTone = obj.getAttribute('data');
        }
    }
}
```

Modify your `validate()` method as such:

```
function validate() {   
      // Show error if the eyeColor or skinTone variables are still an empty string
      if(eyeColor == ''){
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Please select an eye color";
    } else if (skinTone == ''){
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Please select a skin tone";
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi MPaul, I updated my code and it's not working. I'm wondering if I'm putting my eyeColor and skinTone id's in the incorrect spot - should they be in the button class? I'm afraid of doing that because the button class already has an id name.

Comment: Hi MPaul - I understand. I'm using the bootstrap dropdown menu, that's why there are anchor tags. As worked through creating the application and per my research, I now believe I should have used a <select><option> elements instead. Switching this I'm afraid it will ruin my code. I'll give it a try though.

Comment: I've modified my answer to take into account your anchor tags. In a perfectly semantic world `<select>` tags would be preferred, but as to not change your code all that much you can leave them as anchor tags

Comment: Thanks Paul, I'm sorry but I need help with these two lines:You should create 2 global variables and set them as an empty string.

Your 2 functions selectMenu1() and selectMenu2() should update the global variables eyeColor and skinTone respectively with the underlying data attribute of the selected anchor element.  I know what global means but should I name them anything? var eye = ""; var skin = "";

Comment: @Alexandra I've modified my answer to reflect the fact that you've been using a `div` element as a container for your dropdown menu. Once again, as you aren't using a `<select>` element, you lose the ability to rely on the `onchange`event, therefore in order to get around this I simply added an additioanl function which will set your javascript variables based on whichever `<a>` tag was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here is overwriting the innerHTML of your div eyeColor, so it will remove all your links. To display an error message, just put a p tag under your div with nothing inside and overwrite his content.

Comment: Hi Medrupaloscil, can you explain further - "Just put a ...." you don't list what I should put under my div.

Comment: Hi, sorry I just edited it ! I wanted to say a "p" tag. It will display you error message right under your div instead of replacing its content.